# How to preserve SQL data type when using mysqli non-prepared statements

Tags: mysql

I would like to use non-prepared statements using mysqli in PHP and preserve the SQL data type.

The comparison table on [this page on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) it suggests that it is possible to do this:

> **Result set values SQL data types**
>
> **Prepared Statement:** Preserved when fetching
>
> **Non-prepared statement:** Converted to string *or preserved when fetching*

What is meant by fetching?

At present, in code like the following column values are all string. Is there a way to preserve data type without using prepared statements?

```
$conn = new mysqli('db_host', 'db_username', 'db_password', 'db_name');
$conn->set_charset('db_charset');
$result = $conn->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

NB. unbuffered query

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have since found the option mysqli `MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE` that converts numeric columns to `int` or `float` (boolean columns become `int`).

I'm not sure if this is what was referred to in the php.net documentation or if there is another method.

Example:

```
$conn->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, 1);
```